# Is there any way to use pwn tools to find the address of a function in an executable?

Tags: objdump, pwntools

Let's say that I have a simple executable and I want to find the address of the main. Usually, I take the address from the `objdump` output, and then I use it in my `pwn` script. I want to make my script more generic without using any of the hardcoded values from `objdump`. Is there any way to do this with pwn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that I can use ELF object and print addresses for all symbols. You can find more information [here](https://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/elf/elf.html), but a simple example would be:

Find the address for main:

```
elf = ELF('./path_to_your_executable')
addr_main = elf.symbols['main']
```